# Invalid characters in the xml

Tags: xml

All, I am trying to parse a xml in the `XMLSpy`. But XMLSpy just tell me the xml is not well formed.

[image]

I believe it is some invalid characters(`RS`) are included in this xml. Because if I remove it .the validation of XMLSpy is passed. I think that UTF-8 encodeing don't allow this kind of characters . But What If I really want to include this kind of character. Which encoding should I apply ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Control characters are not allowed in XML 1.0 source, even if you use an entity reference like `&x1e;`.  Some edit controls like Scintilla represent control characters like you have shown.  That's `CTRL-^` (also called the Record Separator).  If you want binary data in XML, you have to encode with a [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) scheme.